# Date changed to number format when sheet imported. Excel VBA

Tags: vba, date, excel, format

Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Before importing the data, the date appears to be fine when opened, this is the format:

```
Release Date    Created
24/04/2014      10/03/2014 20:32
```

But after importing into a fresh sheet on my workbook, the date is changed into 5 digits of numbers shown below.

```
Release Date    Created
41753           41708.85556
```

How am I supposed to solve the issue when importing into my sheet? The following is my code for importing sheet to my project.

```
Sub ImptSht()
    Dim altwb As Workbook
    Dim FilePathalt As String
    Dim activeWB As Workbook

    Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    FilePathalt = "C:\DataSheet\workbook.xls"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set altwb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePathalt, Local:=True)

    altwb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
    altwb.Close False

    activeWB.Sheets("shet").Cells.AutoFilter
    activeWB.Sheets("shet").Cells.ClearFormats

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the sheet called "shet" ? i guess if your use `.clearformats` at the end of the copy, well you end up losing formating (dates going to general)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number shown represents a date value. To convert this into a date format, select the column that you would like to convert into a date and use the `NumberFormat` property like so:

```
'Change the column letter to the applicable one
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

Comment: is there any format for date and time?  eg. 10/03/2014 20:32

Comment: Yes you can use `"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"` for example.

Answer (score 2):

The `ClearFormats` is doing that.
Loose that statement.

Comment: And use Gareth's answer if you want to set the format for the date columns again.